# What is the freelancer's responsibility regarding software bugs?

Tags: freelance-websites, legal, consulting, licensing

I just started my career as an online freelancer and even though I try to do my best I have this constant stress & anxiety about what will happen if there is a huge unwanted issue/bug in my code?

For example, what if my software crashes completely because of some bug and causes huge financial/reputation damage to the company?

I always say to clients that I will fix any bugs found for free for at least 6 months, but I'm still concerned, will I be held responsible? what if there is a lot of money involved? should I pay for the damages?

For this reason, I recently started putting [Mozilla Public License 2](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mpl-2.0/)
in all my codes, so basically my customers can even re-sell the code, I rather have that than have stress about the future.

Any advice/legal-notes/ideas are greatly appreciated.

---

**P.S.** I'm a PHP coder so the source is always provided to the customer

**P.P.S.** In case it's relevant, I am diagnosed with [Generalized Anxiety Disorder (GAD)](https://adaa.org/understanding-anxiety/generalized-anxiety-disorder-gad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you've agreed to fix bugs or other defects, that doesn't necessarily make you liable for the damage caused by those defects.

The [Mozilla Public License](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mpl-2.0/), which you're using for your code, includes terms to help protect the code's contributors and distributors against liability:

```
*  7. Limitation of Liability                                          *
*  --------------------------                                          *
*                                                                      *
*  Under no circumstances and under no legal theory, whether tort      *
*  (including negligence), contract, or otherwise, shall any           *
*  Contributor, or anyone who distributes Covered Software as          *
*  permitted above, be liable to You for any direct, indirect,         *
*  special, incidental, or consequential damages of any character      *
*  including, without limitation, damages for lost profits, loss of    *
*  goodwill, work stoppage, computer failure or malfunction, or any    *
*  and all other commercial damages or losses, even if such party      *
*  shall have been informed of the possibility of such damages. This   *
*  limitation of liability shall not apply to liability for death or   *
*  personal injury resulting from such party's negligence to the       *
*  extent applicable law prohibits such limitation. Some               *
*  jurisdictions do not allow the exclusion or limitation of           *
*  incidental or consequential damages, so this exclusion and          *
*  limitation may not apply to You.                                    *
```

Many other popular licenses, such as the [MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) and the [GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html), include similar terms to limit your liability.

To be safe, though, if you want to make sure you're not at risk then you should also consult a lawyer who's familiar with software licensing issues.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what services you provide to your clients, you should invest in Professional Liability Insurance and General Liability Insurance, or their equivalents.

> Will I be held responsible?

You might very well be held responsible. It is your code after all.

> What if there is a lot of money involved? should I pay for the
>   damages?

You might very well be responsible for damages or financial losses.

This is why it's critical that you protect yourself with the appropriate insurance.

Comment: But how do I get an insurance for working on Freelancer.com, there is absolutely no contract between me and the employer, I just set a bid, get approved, do the job and get paid. and I also provide the code under "Mozilla Public License 2"

Comment: It doesn't matter how or where you work or through what agency or website. If a client wants to sue you they'll sue you. Whether or not they have cause. That's what insurance is for. There are many companies that sell PLI and GLI insurance.